# Use concat and lookup on dataverse table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a dataverse table like this:

E-mail:                              EDS:

user1@gmail.com                      221

user1@gmail.com                      123

MyEmail@gmail.com                    13

MyEmail@gmail.com                    21

user3@gmail.com                      123

user4@gmail.com                      221

I want to check which EDS -s have user access on.

for example, if user1 opens app it should return (221; 123)

**Set(currentEDS, Concat(ConnexionConfigs, LookUp(ConnexionConfigs,'E-mail' = User().Email, EDS), "; "))**
that's how my code looks like.
I am logged in with MyEmail@gmail.com, for some reason code returns 21; 21; 21; 21; 21; 21;
there is 21 6 times, I think thats because there is 6 records in my dataverse table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
Concat(Filter(ConnexionConfigs, 'E-mail' = User().Email), EDS, "; ")
```

You may need to change the data source and column names to match with your actual table and column names.

**Documentation**:

1. [Filter, Search, and LookUp functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup)
2. [Concat and Concatenate functions in Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-concatenate)

Comment: I have one more question If you don't mind, now I have AllcurrentEDS = (13; 21) and I have one more table with lots of information including EDS, for example:
country:        EDS:
SPAIN            43
ITALY             44
GEORGIA      21
USA              13.
I have a listbox in app, where my options should only be GEORGIA and USA.

Comment: Try something like this: `Filter(CountryData, EDS in AllcurrentEDS)`. Where `CountryData` is name of your table with data related to country and EDS.

Comment: it returns some uncertain number. blue underline for "in" and delegation warning for listbox, I tried Filter(CountryData, EDS in AllcurrentEDS, country) to, but stil same.

Answer (score 0):

*LookUp function return first record with the matching condition.*

```
  Filter(ConnexionConfigs, 'E-mail' = User().Email,EDS)
```

Filter will give you all the records for MyEmail@gmail.com.
Now you need distinct i.e 2 records for MyEmail@gmail.com

```
Distinct(Filter(ConnexionConfigs, 'E-mail' = User().Email,EDS))
```

Now you can save your these 2 distinict records as collection or you can directly perfrom forall.

For simple understading let's save it as collection

```
ClearCollect( AllcurrentEDS, Distinct(Filter(ConnexionConfigs, 'E-mail' = User().Email,EDS)) )

Concat(AllcurrentEDS, EDS)
```

This should give you desired results.

Comment: 'The function 'Clearcollect' has some invalid arguments'.
It didn't work. maybe I have to change some names in your function, I am beginner, so please explain if something should be changed.
thank you.

Comment: and also, distinct function will remove duplicates and there will be left only one EDS for one email, is it correct?

Comment: no, distinct will give you 2 rows with 13 and 21 as they are distinct. for clearcollect try something like this `ClearCollect( AllcurrentEDS, Distinct(Filter(ConnexionConfigs, 'E-mail' = User().Email)) )`

Comment: I have one more question If you don't mind, now I have AllcurrentEDS = (13; 21) and I have one more table with lots of information including EDS, for example:
country:        EDS:
SPAIN            43
ITALY             44
GEORGIA      21
USA              13.
I have a listbox in app, where my options should only be GEORGIA and USA.